# Binding issue in repeat.for in aurelia

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have a list of cards that i populate, when i click on each card i want to get and display the correct items displayed for that card.
The problem i am facing is that when i return an array its not binding the correct item to the specific card.

This is my HTML

```
<div repeat.for="Grouping of categoryItems">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
                            <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                                <div class="card-content" style="padding:10px">
                                    <span class="card-title white-text truncate">${Grouping.name}</span>
                                    <a if.bind="Grouping.hideDetails" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light" click.delegate="Activate(list, Grouping)"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>                                     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div repeat.for="categoryGroupingTypes of categoryItemTypes">
                        <div class="row" if.bind="!Grouping.hideDetails">


                            
                            <div class="col" style="position:absolute;padding:5%">
                                <div class="rotate-text-90-negative">
                                    <span class="blue-grey-text"><b>${categoryGroupingTypes.name}</b></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div repeat.for="item of categoryItemsTypes.items" class="col s12 m3 l3 ">
                                
                                    <div class="card-content">
                                        <span class="card-title white-text truncate">${items.Name} ${items.Quantity}</span>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                     </div>
```

my ts

```
async Activate(list: ListModel[], grouping: any) {
            
        this.categoryItemsTypes = await this.getTypes(list);
        let result = this.categoryItem.filter(x => x.name == grouping.name)
        if (result) {
            grouping.hideDetails = false;
        }
            
    }
```

so this.categoryItemsTypes has the following array

```
0: {name: "Clothes", items: Array(3)}
1: {name: "Shoes", items: Array(2)}
```

so when the page loads it loads the cards as follows

[image: LOADS GROUPING NAME NAME]

then when i click on "Clothes"
i only want it to load the array associated with clothes and if "shoes" is clicked then only load that array as follows

[image: what i want]

but what is currently happening with my above code is the following

[image: wrong]

this line is where i bind the items

```
repeat.for="item of categoryItemsTypes.items"
```

how can i bind the items to the correct ${Grouping.name} as shown in picture 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the right direction, but not complete yet.
Array assignment are not observed by aurelia.
In general, when populating arrays with a new set of elements, this is a good way:

`destarray.splice(0, destarray.length, ...sourcearray);`

over

`destarray = sourcearray;`

because the former is observed by aurelia by default and the latter is not.